# Verificar se a String é número, se não, retornar erro ao usuário

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um código em Java usando JOptionPane, e nele, criei um InputDialog que devolve o valor "1","2" ou "3" digitado pelo usuário para uma variável String chamada "retorno". Feito isso, preciso converte-la em int, usando o `Integer.parseInt()`. Porém, **se o usuário digitar algo que não seja número daria erro na execução na hora de converter para inteiro**, e eu não quero isso.

```
String retorno;
int op;

retorno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " 1- Criar uma conta \n 2- Acessar uma conta \n 3- Sair");
op = Integer.parseInt(retorno); //se não for número, da erro =/
```

Como construir o código para quando o usuário inserir um valor, certificar-se que ele seja número, e caso não for, **retornar um erro ao usuário ao invés de dar pau e parar a execução**?

Comment: Você só pretende aceitar os valores 1, 2 ou 3?

Comment: @jbueno sim! Apenas estes valores.

Comment: http://www.guj.com.br/java/66577-como-verifiar-se-a-string-e-letra-ou-numero

Comment: Você só pode escolher uma resposta como a _"correta"_ ;-) PS: fique a vontade para escolher aquela que você achou a mais adequada para a sua situação.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como se trata de apenas 3 valores, você pode fazer um `switch-case` para cada uma das opções. É menos custoso do que lançar uma exceção.

Código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String retorno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " 1- Criar uma conta \n 2- Acessar uma conta \n 3- Sair");
        int op=0;
        switch (retorno) {
        case "1":
            op=1;
            break;
        case "2":
            op=2;
            break;
        case "3":
            op=3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(op);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Há várias formas de fazer isso, como você vai fazer depende um pouco de gosto e também da complexidade da sua aplicação, mas vamos lá.

Se for uma aplicação pequena e você só pretende validar se a entrada do usuário é igual a **1**, **2** ou **3** é melhor fazer um `switch-case` validando se a entrada é um desses valores.

```
retorno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " 1- Criar uma conta \n 2- Acessar uma conta \n 3- Sair");
switch (retorno)
{
    case "1":
        //Operação 1
    case "2":
        //Operação 2
    case "3":
        //Operação 3
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entrada inválida", "Alerta", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Uma das maneiras seria envolver com `try/catch`, capturando um `NumberFormarException`. Se lançar a exceção, você retorna o erro no `catch`.

```
try{
op = Integer.parseInt(retorno);

}catch(NumberFormatException ex){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"opção inválida","Alerta",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Lembrando que onde está `null` você pode referenciar o `Jframe` da sua tela.

**Referencias:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102916/5524514

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! ^^

Answer (score 4):

Como alternativa você pode criar um método que verifica os caracteres pra ver se é uma `String` ou `Integer`.

Exemplo:

```
public static boolean validarString(String texto) {
        String valor = texto;
        boolean valido = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < valor.length(); i++) {
            Character caractere = valor.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isDigit(caractere)) {
                //É String
                valido = false;
            }
        }
        //É numero
        return valido == true;
    }
```

Depois no Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         String retorno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " 1- Criar uma conta \n 2- Acessar uma conta \n 3- Sair");
         if(validarString(retorno)){
             System.out.println("Numero");
         }else{
             System.err.println("String");
         }
    }
```