# Convertendo string para long int

Tags: java, tipagem

Tenho uma atividade para fazer na qual o professor pede que sejam convertidos os nomes dos números nos números inteiros (*long int*).

Gostaria de saber se em Java existe alguma função que faça isso... Pesquisei em alguns lugares, mas não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar até então.

O código que eu fiz está apenas imprimindo o número como caractere sem essa conversão de que o problema fala.

```
    public static void converte(String entrada) {

    switch (entrada) {

    case "um":
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case "dois":
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    case "três":
        System.out.println("3");
        break;
    case "quatro":
        System.out.println("4");
        break;
    case "cinco":
        System.out.println("5");
        break;
    case "seis":
        System.out.println("6");
        break;
    case "sete":
        System.out.println("7");
        break;
    case "oito":
        System.out.println("8");
        break;
    case "nove":
        System.out.println("9");
        break;
    case "dez":
        System.out.println("10");
        break;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(
            "Inicialização...\nInstruções:\n1-Digite o nome de um número entre um~dez.\n2-O programa encerra ao digitar 'fim'.");

    while (true) {
        String entrada = key.nextLine();

        if (entrada.equals("fim")) {
            break;
        }

        converte(entrada);

    }

    System.out.println("Fim!");

    key.close();
}
```

Comment: Mostre o que você fez ate agora, clicando em EDITAR e adicionando na pergunta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como dividir uma `string` e depois converter para int?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101117/verificar-se-a-string-é-número-se-não-retornar-erro-ao-usuário)

Comment: Não tem nada pronto no Java (pode ser que alguém criou algo fora). O problema aqui é a definição do problema. Sem saber exatamente qual é o problema não tem como achar uma solução certa. O que deseja fazer de fato? Criar uma função que recebe um número por extenso e retornar um número mesmo (`long`)? Se deve retornar `long` então não pode ficar de 1 a 10. Se for isso o algoritmo é absurdamente mais complexo do que está fazendo, nem dá para começar te ajudar. Se quer saber como retornar o número em vez de imprimir, aí é fácil, mas duvido que só isto resolva o problema.

Comment: "Implemente uma classe que pega as os dez primeiros números por extenso (de “um” a “dez”) e converte-os em inteiros (long int). 
Use o condicional switch para a conversão"
Esse é o problema proposto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho estranho pedir um `long` para isso, mas vamos lá.

Pelo enunciado a função deve retornar um `long` e não um `void`. E não deve imprimir nada, basta retornar o valor, e já pode ser um inteiro, não tem porque usar um caractere com o dígito.

Também é bom tratar o caso de ser digitado algo inválido, por isso criei o `default`.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static long converte(String entrada) {
        switch (entrada) {
        case "um":
            return 1;
        case "dois":
            return 2;
        case "três":
            return 3;
        case "quatro":
            return 4;
        case "cinco":
            return 5;
        case "seis":
            return 6;
        case "sete":
            return 7;
        case "oito":
            return 8;
        case "nove":
            return 9;
        case "dez":
            return 10;
        default:
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inicialização...\nInstruções:\n1-Digite o nome de um número entre um~dez.\n2-O programa encerra ao digitar 'fim'.");
        while (true) {
            String entrada = key.nextLine();
            if (entrada.equals("fim")) break;
            long convertido = converte(entrada);
            if (convertido == -1) {
                System.out.println("Palavra inválida");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(convertido);
        }
        System.out.println("Fim!");
        key.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SerabM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pwnafeto-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/WordsToNumber.java).

Comment: Caramba, valeu mesmo... Agora acho que fez sentido. Fiz besteira na interpretação do enunciado mesmo. Mas obrigado, deu uma iluminada aqui.

Comment: Surgiu um dúvida boba aqui, dentro dos cases do switch, não estou vendo o break, já que ele possui um tipo de retorno ele dispensa o uso do break?

Comment: Não é por causa do tipo de retorno, é porque ele tem um `return` dentro dele. Este comando faz sair do método naquele momento, se tivesse um `break` ali em seguida quando ele seria executado?

Comment: Entendi, como o return precisa ser o último comando ele encerra, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String letras = "um dois tres quatro cinco seis sete oito nove dez";
private static final long[] numeros = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

private static long converter(String entrada) {
    String string = Normalizer.normalize(entrada.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]",
            "");
    for (int i = 0; i < letras.split(" ").length; i++)
        if (string.equals(letras.split(" ")[i]))
            return numeros[i];
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Insira o valor:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        long valor = converter(scanner.nextLine());
        if (valor == -1) {
            System.out.println("Erro: numero invalido");
            scanner.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Convertido -> " + valor);
        }
    }
}
```